# Do Rust collections have the ability to own the data they store?

Tags: rust, ownership-semantics

Given the following code (which does not compile):

```
fn main() {
    let mut v = vec!();

    {
        let name = "Bob the Builder".to_string();

        v.push(&name);
    }

    for m in &v{
        println!("{}", m);
    }
}
```

I have created a variable binding to a Rust `String` type which will go out of scope within the first set of curly braces. **Is there a way to somehow move the ownership of the String such that the vector itself owns it?**

This is an arbitrary example however I'm just trying to understand if this concept is possible.

I already know that if I use a string literal this will be regarded as a static string which will exist for the lifetime of the entire app and therefore this code would compile but I'm just trying to understand if a collection in Rust can own data. I know Rust is not Objective-C but Objective-C has collections with the ability to retain their data.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The vector will own it.. as long as you don't pass a reference to it.

Changing your code to this:

```
fn main() {
    let mut v = vec!();
    {
        let name = "Bob the Builder".to_string();

        v.push(name); // <--- no ampersand

        println!("{}", name); // <---- error, use of moved value
    }

    for m in &v {
        println!("{}", m);
    }
}
```

..throws an error because `name` is now owned by the Vector. If you allow for the fact that the Vector now owns the string.. your code compiles (by removing my `println!` call):

```
fn main() {
    let mut v = vec!();
    {
        let name = "Bob the Builder".to_string();

        v.push(name); // <--- no ampersand
    }

    for m in &v {
        println!("{}", m); // <--- works fine
    }
}
```

So your problem is that you're passing a reference to your string into the vector. Essentially, at the end of the block your `name` value will be dropped and your `&name` reference in the Vector could potentially point to invalid memory.. making `v[0].something_here()` potentially dangerous. So the compiler stops you. *But*, if you transfer ownership of the `name` variable into the vector (by not passing a reference.. but passing the whole thing) then Rust knows to clean the string up when it cleans the Vector up.

Comment: This is one of those doh! moments...when you say it like that...makes perfect sense.  Thanks for helping me.

Comment: @RalphCaraveo When learning new languages, I always recommend [rubber duck debugging](http://www.rubberduckdebugging.com/).